# key generation using RandomStringUtils in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi in my spring mvc app i have used below code for generating serial key for activating the application.The key consist of 12 characters with alpha numerics.

```
 RandomStringUtils.random(12, true, true).toUpperCase().toString()
```

Is this proper way to generate unique key using RandomStringUtils and what happens it will reach its limit.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of that function but calling `toUpperCase` on the string does not look correct as it doubles the frequency of the letters compared to the digits.

Comment: clients need keys in upper case that's why toUpperCase

Comment: In the original string `a`, `A`, and `1` will appear with the same frequency. If you now map `a` to `A`, you will have twice as many `A` than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use method which particularly meets your requirement.

> public static String randomAlphanumeric(int count)
>
> ```
> Creates a random string whose length is the number of characters specified.
>
> Characters will be chosen from the set of alpha-numeric characters.
>
> Parameters:
>     count - the length of random string to create
> Returns:
>     the random string
> ```